# DynamoDB table from AWS Android SDK sample app is not in console

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am working with the UserPreferenceDemo, one of Amazon's Android SDK sample apps. This app utilizes a TVM (token vending machine) and DynamoDB. Our of the box, the app seems to work as it should: it creates a table, populates it, and you can view it on the app. However, the table does not seem to show up in my DynamoDB console. I am very confused, has anyone had a similar issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The UserPreferenceDemo app creates the DynamoDB table in the [US-WEST-2 region](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-android/blob/master/samples/DynamoDB_UserPreference/src/com/amazonaws/tvmclient/AmazonClientManager.java#L103). If you change the region selector drop down in the top right of the AWS Management Console to **US West 2 (Oregon)**, you should be able to see the table.

Comment: Thank you! That was in fact the issue.